# Maximum recursion depth exceeded when inheriting class

Tags: python, python-3.x, inheritance, recursion, scikit-learn

I'm attempting to extend the `DBSCAN` class from [scikit-learn](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.DBSCAN.html) in another class, `MyDBSCAN`, but I'm running into recursion limits and I can't work out why it's happening.

I've reduced the problem to an the following code:

```
from sklearn.cluster import DBSCAN

class MyDBSCAN(DBSCAN):
    def __init__(eps=0.5, min_samples=5, metric='euclidean', metric_params=None, algorithm='auto', leaf_size=30, p=None, n_jobs=1):
        super().__init__(eps, min_samples, metric, metric_params, algorithm, leaf_size, p, n_jobs)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    items = [[1], [2], [3], [4]]
    clusterer = MyDBSCAN()
    clusterer.fit(items)
```

Running the above with the DBSCAN class works fine, but when using MyDBSCAN, I get the following output:

```
File "./MyDBSCAN.py", line 11, in <module>
    clusterer.fit(items)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/sklearn/cluster/dbscan_.py", line 281, in fit
    **self.get_params())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/sklearn/base.py", line 244, in get_params
    deep_items = value.get_params().items()
...
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/sklearn/base.py", line 244, in get_params
    deep_items = value.get_params().items()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/sklearn/base.py", line 227, in get_params
    for key in self._get_param_names():
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/sklearn/base.py", line 197, in _get_param_names
    init_signature = signature(init)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/inspect.py", line 2055, in signature
    return _signature_internal(obj)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/inspect.py", line 1953, in _signature_internal
    return Signature.from_function(obj)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/inspect.py", line 2458, in from_function
    __validate_parameters__=is_duck_function)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/inspect.py", line 2374, in __init__
    for param in parameters))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/collections/__init__.py", line 60, in __init__
    self.__update(*args, **kwds)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/_collections_abc.py", line 590, in update
    if isinstance(other, Mapping):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/abc.py", line 188, in __instancecheck__
    subclass in cls._abc_negative_cache):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/_weakrefset.py", line 75, in __contains__
    return wr in self.data
RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in comparison
```

I tried overriding `get_params()` like so, but to no avail:

```
def get_params():
    super().get_params()
```

Comment: You forgot the `self` argument!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't solve all of your problem here, but `__init__` should have `self` as its first argument.

Comment: That was the issue!